# Knowledge of $\frac{x}{e^{x}-1}$

Tags: convex-analysis, applications

I wonder if anyone has seen the function $\frac{x}{exp(x)-1}$ in some application or otherwise has some information about it.

A visual inspection e.g. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2F%28exp%28x%29-1%29 demonstrates it is convex.

Erling

Answer (score 2):

The coefficents of the Taylor series of $\frac x{\exp(x)-1}$ at $0$ are the [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number). More precisely:$$\frac x{\exp(x)-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{B_nx^n}{n!}.$$And they have *lots* of applications.

Comment: There also seem to be relation to the Lambert W function. See "Bernoulli numbers and Todd genus" at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Answer (score 2):

The way to see that it is convex is to show that it is always decreasing and concave up.

To show decreasing, you differentiate it, and you get $$\frac{(e^x-1)-xe^x}{(e^x-1)^2}$$
Assuming $x\neq 0$, the bottom is positive, and does not affect the sign, so we need to show that the top is always negative.  In other words,
$$e^x-1-xe^x<0$$
$$e^x(1-x)<1$$
$$e^x<1/(1-x)$$

Expanding a Taylor expansion, we see that in fact,

$$1+x+x^2/2+x^3/6+\ldots<1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots{\rm\ \ for\ all\ }x\neq 0$$

Then, we can do a similar analysis on the second derivative.  This derivative is:$$
\left(\frac{e^x(1-x)-1}{(e^x-1)^2}\right)'=\frac{(e^x+e^x(1-x))(e^x-1)^2-(e^x(1-x)-1)(2e^x(e^x-1))}{(e^x-1)^4}=\frac{e^x(2-x)(e^x-1)-2e^{2x}(1-x)+2e^x}{(e^x-1)^3}=\frac{e^x(2e^x-xe^x-2+x-2e^x+2xe^x+2)}{(e^x-1)^3}=\frac{e^x(xe^x+x)}{(e^x-1)^3}=\frac{xe^x(e^x+1)}{(e^x-1)^3}
$$

To show that this is always positive (for $x\neq 0$), we note that $e^x$ and $e^x+1$ are always positive, so they don't affect the sign.  Also, it's clear that $x$ and $(e^x-1)$ are both negative for $x<0$, and positive for $x>0$.  Therefore, this quotient is always positive, proving what you noticed in your post.

Answer (score 0):

The integral $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x}{e^x-1}dx$$ is $\zeta(2)$, which is famously equal to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ (Basel Problem).

This is actually a fairly important integral. For example, in physics you have [Planck's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law), which is to do with blackbody radiation (which led to the development of quantum mechanics). Using Planck's Law, you can derive the [Stefan-Boltzmann Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law). This involves evaluating a multiple of the integral
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^3}{e^x-1}dx$$
which is equal to $$6\zeta(4)=\frac{\pi^4}{15}$$
There are various ways of showing this, but one method involves computing the Fourier series for $x^4$ in $[-\pi,\pi]$, which is
$$x^4=\frac{\pi^4}{5}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{8n^2\pi^2-48}{n^4}\right)\cos 
n\pi\cos nx$$
Leading to
$$\pi^4=\frac{\pi^4}{5}+8\pi^2\zeta(2)-48\zeta(4)$$
(Using the series definition of $\zeta$)

And as I said earlier,
$$\zeta(2)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x}{e^x-1}dx$$

Again, we can consider the Fourier Series of $x^2$ in $[-\pi,\pi]$:
$$x^2=\frac{\pi^2}{3}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{4\cos n\pi\cos nx}{n^2}$$
Meaning
$$\pi^2=\frac{\pi^2}{3}+4\zeta(2)\Rightarrow\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$